# c++ validation login code

Tags: c++, validation, authentication

i am trying to make a simple validation user name and password for my program.
i am not sure whats wrong with my code, but i think i have some logic error

here is my piece of code

```
          string usernameinput,passinput;
string username[]={"mmm","nnnn","rrrr","aaa"};
string password[]={"1234","1212","1234","1212"};
bool flag=false;

while(flag==false){
  cout << "username: "<<endl;
    cin>>usernameinput;
    cout << "password: "<<endl;
        cin>>passinput;
        for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
            if(usernameinput ==username[i] && passinput==password[i] )
            {
                flag=true;
            }
            else if (usernameinput !=username[i] && passinput!=password[i])
            {
                flag=false;
    cout<<"please enter correct username and password"<<endl;
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Off topic: rather than separating the passwords and user names into their own arrays use a pairing structure to group them and have only one array. Less book-keeping required.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second `if` statement, `else` will suffice. Even if you keep it, it has to be an `||` not `&&`, because either one not matching is a case for setting the flag to false.

In fact, you don't need even the `else` statement. Since you are initialising the flag to `false`, it will remain `false` until it is set to `true`, which will happen only when username and password both match. Once there is a match, you want to stop comparing, so you have to use `break` to end the `for` loop. The error message should be outside the `for` loop as you don't want it to show until you have checked against all the values.

```
bool flag=false;

while(flag==false){
    cout << "username: "<<endl;
    cin>>usernameinput;
    cout << "password: "<<endl;
    cin>>passinput;
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
        if(usernameinput ==username[i] && passinput==password[i] )
        {
            flag=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$flag) {
        cout<<"please enter correct username and password"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The program does not stop searching for a match after a match is found. Since the values tested after the match will not be a match, chaos ensues.

Let's watch that happens when we execute the following code for input of  *mmm* and *1234* for user name and password, respectively:

```
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
    if(usernameinput ==username[i] && passinput==password[i] )
    {
        flag=true;
    }
    else if (usernameinput !=username[i] && passinput!=password[i])
    {
        flag=false;
        cout<<"please enter correct username and password"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Iteration 1:

```
    if("mmm" == "mmm"  && "1234" == "1234" ) // both true. Enter
    {
        flag=true; // flag is now true
    }
    else if ("mmm" != "mmm"  && "1234" != "1234")
    {
        flag=false;
        cout<<"please enter correct username and password"<<endl;
    }
```

Now, since nothing tells the program that match has been found and we can stop looking, we proceed to iteration 2:

```
    if("mmm" == "nnnn"  && "1234" == "1212" ) // false
    {
        flag=true; 
    }
    else if ("mmm" != "mmm"  && "1234" != "1234") // both false, enter
    {
        flag=false; // flag is now false Ooops. 
        cout<<"please enter correct username and password"<<endl;
    }
```

Output, even though the credentials were correct, `flag` will be false and the user will be alerted to the false negative three times. Yuck.

```
please enter correct username and password
please enter correct username and password
please enter correct username and password
```

We needed to exit the loop when we got a match. The obvious solution is something like:

```
    if(usernameinput ==username[i] && passinput==password[i] )
    {
        flag=true;
        break;
    }
```

But wait! There's more! What if the input is *mmm* and *1235*?

Iteration 1:

```
    if("mmm" == "mmm"  && "1235" == "1234" ) //Second case fails
    {
        flag=true; 
        break;
    }
    else if ("mmm" != "mmm"  && "1234" != "1234") // first case fails
    {
        flag=false;
        cout<<"please enter correct username and password"<<endl;
    }
```

We don't enter *either* case. `flag` remains false and the intruder doesn't get in, but this just looks ugly and still gives you the three error messages. We can do better.

## Solution

Make a function:

```
bool checkcredentials(const std::string & uname,
                     const std::string & pword)
{
    bool rval = false;
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        if(uname== username[i])
        {
            if (pword==password[i])
            {
                rval = true; // could just return true here, but some folk get uptight 
                             // over multiple returns in a function
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return rval;
}
```

The calling function does something like

```
if (checkcredentials(usernameinput, passinput))
{
    // let the user in.
}
else
{
    cout<<"please enter correct username and password"<<endl;
}
```

Note that the check password function does nothing but check credentials. All of the communicating with the user is done elsewhere. This keeps the function dead simple. It does only one thing, and it is the one thing described by the function name.

Security note: before returning a message to the user wait some small random amount of time. This messes with the heads of anyone who is trying to guess the size of the credentials or the size of the credentials database by timing the response.

This can be cleaned up further by pairing the username with the password and having only one array. This ensures that usernames are matched up with passwords and no one added a user name without adding a password.

```
pair<string, string> credentials[]={ // array of pairs
    {"mmm",  "1234"},
    {"nnnn", "1212"},
    {"rrrr", "1234"},
    {"aaa",  "1212"}
 };

bool checkcredentials(const std::string & uname,
                      const std::string & pword)
{
    bool rval = false;
    for(auto & cred: credentials)
    {
        if(uname == cred.first)
        {
            if (pword == cred.second)
            {
                rval = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return rval;
}
```

[Documentation on pair.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)

And this can be improved with a smarter datastructure. `map` is an associative container that makes looking up a value , password in this case, based on a key, user name.

```
map<string, string> credentials={
    {"mmm",  "1234"},
    {"nnnn", "1212"},
    {"rrrr", "1234"},
    {"aaa",  "1212"}
 };

bool checkcredentials(const std::string & uname,
                      const std::string & pword)
{
    auto cred = credentials.find(uname); // look for user name
    if (cred != credentials.end() && // username exists
            cred->second == pword) // password matches
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Documentation on map.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)